# Camera's Linux system cannot run compiled C program with './abcd', recognises it as a /bin/sh script instead

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling

recently I started to do some scripting with my camera. I made a simple hello world program in C, compiled it and sent it too my camera.

The camera's system is a very bare bones version of Linux. Running `uname` gives me Linux, and `uname -r` gives me 2.6.35. Bash is not installed on this system.

When I execute any C executable, it thinks that it is a script, giving me the error:
`./helloworld: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's your camera, and what processor does it have? If it isn't an x86 CPU, did you crosscompile / set the correct CPU/architecture flags? How do you start the software? What does `file helloworld` say?

Comment: @dseifert The camera runs through an Axis Communications Q7404 video encoder. Since it is very barebones, the `file` command doesn't even exist.

Comment: @dseifert I have no idea what the processor is or what the CPU is, all that I ever did was enable ssh on the camera through editcgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you compiled your hello world program on your 64 bit desktop PC using something like `gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c`.

The resulting binary is meant for AMD64 architecture (think Intel 64 bit) and won't run on any other processor type. I.e. it is incompatible with the target system (= your camera) which uses the 32 bit ARTPEC-3 processor with a CRISv32 architecture.

This means that you must cross-compile your program for the camera's CPU. Check e.g. http://developer.axis.com/wiki/doku.php%3Fid=axis:compiling_for_cris_howto.html which looks like a very good tutorial on getting your first program to run on your camera.

Comment: thanks! I will definitely try this out when I wake up tommorow

Comment: Hmmm, when I went to find the install for gcc-cris which was included in their SDK, They indicated it was discontinued. Quite unforunate. I might have to dig deeper for older archives of the SDK.
http://www.axis.com/nz/en/support/downloads/software-development-kit

Comment: Nevermind! I think I have found arguments to add what kind of architecture I am compiling for in gcc. Thanks.

Comment: Alright just one last update, I found all the cris tools @ https://github.com/matthazinski/cris-dist  

Thanks for all the help!